# How would I go about calling a batch command from a HTML button

Tags: html, batch-file

I'm making a program, It's a simple .bat file, I recently started learning HTML5 so I could make some UI, now I've stumbled across a problem, I'm unsure if possible then how one would go about calling a batch command when a HTML button is pressed, Here's the script;

```html
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal

echo Select an option:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply: "%HTAreply%"
goto :EOF
-->


<HTML>
<button onclick="closeHTA(1);">Exit</button>
<br>
<br>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >

<TITLE>Console</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.resizeTo(1000,640);

function closeHTA(reply){
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply);
   window.close();
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   <button onclick="THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP">Google Chrome</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!   Do note: I'm fairly new to HTML5 and don't understand everything, so a detailed explaination of the solution would be nice!

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand the comment correctly, but what I was looking for was more of activating a part of the same file, thanks for the comment though!